# How to update a state that is compost by a array of objects with ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, state, updating

I have the following state:

```
  const [competitorsData, setCompetitorData] = useState([
    { name: "Ana", speed: "2 months", color: "green" },
    { name: "John", speed: "3 weeks", color: "white" },
    { name: "Stevan", speed: "3 days", color: "gray" }
  ]);
```

This is how I am displaying it:

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Speed</th>
          <th>Color</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {competitorsData.map((info) => (
          <tr key={info.name}>
            <td>{info.name}</td>
            <td>{info.speed}</td>
            <td>{info.color}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

The problem is I need a way to update speed to hours, the solution that I thought was to create a `useEffect` that uses `.split(" ")` so I could convert the values to hours, but how would it be possible to insert the converted values back to the state?

```
  let elementSplitedConverted = 0;
  useEffect(() => {
    competitorsData.map((element, index) => {
      const elementSplited = element.speed.split(" ");
      switch (elementSplited[1]) {
        case "day" || "days":
          elementSplitedConverted = elementSplited * 24;
          break;
        case "week" || "weeks":
          elementSplitedConverted = elementSplited * 168;
          break;
        case "month" || "months":
          elementSplitedConverted = elementSplited * 730;
          break;
        default:
          element.consumablesHours = 0;
          break;
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

I have the code running right here: https://codesandbox.io/s/changing-data-in-array-of-objects-cpo0d?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What action will update the state, a click to a button or something of that sort?

Comment: actually no, the data should be changed before it is displayed to the user

Comment: You could simply create a function that changed your cusotm time to hours by whatever logic you wish. Change `{info.speed}` into `{toHours(info.speed)}` (or call the function however you like) and create a function `const toHours = (speed) => { // ur logic here // }`. If you gonna stick with ur correct hour conversion logic, you cna return straight in a switch case without needing a variable like so `case "day" || "days": return elementSplited[0] * 24`.

Comment: or, if you wish to do in a `useEffect`, before the `.map` create an empty array `const newArr = []`. Now in a switch, in a case just do `newArr.push({... element, speed: elementSplited[0] * 24}); break;` and after `.map` do a `setCompetitorData(newArr)`

Comment: Here is an example i made with `useEffect` for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/changing-data-in-array-of-objects-forked-8m8hf?file=/src/App.js It uses a secondary state `renderData` as the `competitorsData` could be fetched from an API hence you should not change it. It uses same logic as yours, i just fixed `switch` case and, since the data can be empty at the start, made it so if there si no data - it would render a `loading` message rather then an empty table.

Comment: And here is an example with a method that i mentioned before: https://codesandbox.io/s/changing-data-in-array-of-objects-forked-j527l?file=/src/App.js uses same switch logic as yours, just no `useEffect`, 1 less `state` and calculations on the spot. `useEffect` should only be used whenever you require to re-render a component do to data change like to refresh data from an API, recalculate something because somewhere a state, or a value of a variable, changed, etc.

Comment: Thank you Lith, those solutions were great! 